# Using Centralized model of EA for my project

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am using a centralized model for EA project with  one MSSQL instance installed in the cloud - connected to my developers at different location through network.
My developers have an issue that while accessing the centralized model and drawing a sequence diagram takes 72 Sec to connect.
Could you kindly support for the following :
1. If WAN optimizer will increase the performance ?
2. Is distributed model of EA Database a recommended model of usage ??
3. Does EA provide auto synchronization of DB in distributed model ??
4. How is EA- cloud services enabled ??

Answer (score 1):

WAN optimizer will improve it, but just a bit. This is most likely some network issue you're encountering. If you get stuck with it you should contact Sparx support via mail. They are quite responsive helping users out of such dilemma.

You can (if the network issue can't be solved) switch to distributed EAP files and version control. Of course you loose the ability to work synchronously and will see changes from others only after a Get Latest.

EA needs the user to trigger a synchronization if you use the version control feature. While a package is checked out by a single user it can't be changed by others. That might lead to locking, especially if the model cut is sub-optimal.

The cloud DB is rather new. I doubt it will improve performance but can't talk from experience.

Comment: Not worth its own answer so I'll just add it here: to set up your own "cloud"-based repository you need the cloud service server, which you can download from the Sparx web site (requires free registration). I agree with Mr Kilian that it's not likely to be the solution to any network performance issues.

Comment: Hey Uffe, makes me feel older than I already am if you use my last name ;-D